# How do I nest this for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to create an image with a pattern of a repeated circle. I am doing this in PHP with GD. So far I have been able to tile the circle in horizontal manner (x-axis) but am unable to tile it in the vertical(y-axis). Here is an example image.

[image]

Below is the code that created the above image :

```
$width = 1000; 
$height = 500;

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
$color = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 255, 0); 

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
        if ($i % 2 !== 0){ //only if odd numbers
        imagefilledellipse ($image_p, 50 * $i, 50, 100, 100, $color);
        }   

    }

imagejpeg($image_p, uniqid() .'.jpg');
```

My guess is that in order to tile each circle in a vertical manner it just needs another nested `for loop` and it would be similar to one already there except the change in y-axis like so :

`imagefilledellipse ($image_p, 50, 50 * $i, 100, 100, $color);`

I have tried a lot of nesting variation but could not get it to work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `imagefilledellipse` has the following signature (I suppose):

```
imagefilledellipse(image, x, y, width, height, color)
```

Which means that you are drawing for every `i` in `0 < i < 10` a circle with a different `x` position.

Swap it with the `y` parameter to draw vertical circles:

```
$width = 1000; 
$height = 500;

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
$color = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 255, 0); 

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
        if ($i % 2 !== 0){ //only if odd numbers
        imagefilledellipse ($image_p, 50, 50 * $i, 100, 100, $color);
        }   

    }

imagejpeg($image_p, uniqid() .'.jpg');
```

In order to draw both horizontal and vertical circles you will need indeed, as you said, a nested for-loop:

```
$width = 1000; 
$height = 500;

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 
$color = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 255, 0); 

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
        for ($j = 0; $j <= 10; $j++) {
            if ($i % 2 !== 0 && $j % 2 !== 0) { //only if odd numbers
                imagefilledellipse ($image_p, 50 * $i, 50 * $j, 100, 100, $color);
            }   
        }
    }

imagejpeg($image_p, uniqid() .'.jpg');
```

---

Also, you do not need to check for odd numbers if you would change the scale from `i * 50` to `50 + i * 100`, like this:

```
imagefilledellipse ($image_p, 50 + 100 * $i, 50 + 100 * $j, 100, 100, $color);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to draw both vertical and horizontal circles.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you. Look at these HAPPY CIRCLES -  http://postimg.org/image/uzr6pf20b/ :)

Comment: @gurung They look like a great bunch of circles!

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many columns you want it should be quite easy.

```
$colCounter=0;
$yAxis = 50;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++){
    if ($i % 2 !== 0){ //only if odd numbers
        if ($colCounter % 5 === 0){ // Do something every 5 cols
            $yAxis = $yAxis + 50 // add 50 onto each row
        }
        $colCounter++;//increment counter
        imagefilledellipse ($image_p, 50 * $i, $yAxis, 100, 100, $color);
    }   
}
```

Note this is un-tested code